# How to put a geographical map over 2D data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

have two vectors of sizes 441*1 and 681*1, these go from 70 to -40 and from 45 to -125 respectively. The first is a list of latitudes and the second a list of longitudes. I have also a 681*441 matrix with data. I can plot it with contourf, but I would like to insert a geographical map to make the geographical regions easier to identify.

I have tried using geoshow, but I don't understand well what I have to use as an input there.

Any suggestions on how to plot said map are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that this can be done just using load coastlines and then plotting (coastlon, coastlat) over the already generated grid. later on, axis can be used to remove the regions in which there is no data avaiable.